# es6 class variable cannot be read (cannot read property '...' of undefined)

Tags: javascript, express, ecmascript-6

So I just dove into es6 for the first time and wanted to use the new Classes, but I'm running into a strange problem. All classes work fine and write/read their class variables just fine. But one class is not doing so well.

I'm currently getting this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'product' of undefined
at getProducts (***/controllers/ProductController.js:41:13)`

I'm writing a REST API for a school assignment using the MEAN Stack.

In short what's currently happening

*index.js*

```
// dependencies
const Api  = require('./routes/api')

class Rest
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.api = new Api()
        this.init()
    }

    init()
    {
        ... // express server configuration

        // routes
        this.routes()
    }

    // set routes
    routes()
    {
        app.use('/api', this.api.getRouter())
    }
}

new Rest()
```

*/routes/api.js*

```
// dependencies
const express = require('express')
const Products = require('./api/products')

class Api
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.router = express.Router()
        this.products = new Products()
        this.routes()
    }

    getRouter() { return this.router }

    routes()
    {
        // product routes
        this.router.use('/products', this.products.getRouter())
    }
}


// return routes
module.exports = Api
```

*routes/api/products.js*

```
// dependencies
const express = require('express')
const productController = require('../../controllers/ProductController')

class Product
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.router = express.Router()
        this.controller = new productController()
        this.routes()
    }

    getRouter() { return this.router }

    // set header options
    setCollectionOptions(req, res, next)
    {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, OPTIONS')
        next()
    }

    // set routes
    routes()
    {
        this.router.route('/')
            .options([this.setCollectionOptions, this.controller.getOptions])
            .get([this.setCollectionOptions, this.controller.getProducts])
    }
}

// return routes
module.exports = Product
```

*models/Product.js*

```
// dependencies
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const mongoosePaginate = require('mongoose-paginate')

// create schema for model
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    sku: String,
    price: String,
    created_at: { type: String, default: Date.now },
    updated_at: { type: String, default: Date.now }
})
productSchema.plugin(mongoosePaginate)

// export model
module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', productSchema)
```

*controllers/ProductController.js*

```
// dependencies
const express = require('express')

class ProductController
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.product = require('../models/product')
    }


    getProducts(req, res, next)
    {
        this.product.find() // error occurs here!
        ... // rest of the code
    }
}
```

The error occurs at `this.product.find()`

when I `console.log(this.product)`, immediately after I set it, it returns just fine. But when I request the page with a GET at `http://localhost:port/api/products` I receive this error.

Also, when I try to use a method in the ProductController it results in the same error. For example:

```
class ProductController
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.product = require('../models/product')
    }

    init()
    {
        console.log('hi!')
    }

    getProducts(req, res, next)
    {
        this.init()

        ... // rest of code
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

In routes/api/products.js, you are just passing in the methods, which means that when they're invoked they won't have `this` set. You need to bind them, e.g.:

```
.get([this.setCollectionOptions.bind(this), this.controller.getProducts.bind(this.controller)])
```

or use arrow functions, though that requires care with the number of arguments:

```
.get([(req, res, next) => this.setCollectionOptions(req, res, next), (req, res, next) => this.controller.getProducts(req, res, next)])
```

Don't forget to do this for the methods being passed to .options too.

Comment: You'd need to bind it to `this.controller` though. Maybe an arrow function is an easier solution.

Comment: @Bergi, thanks, good catch about the receiver. Added arrow example too.

Comment: If you don't know the number of arguments or there are too many to spell them out, you can also use rest/spread syntax: `(...args) => this.controller.getProducts(...args)`